# Why my training loss decreases first then increases reguarly in each epoch?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

In each epoch, my training loss first decreases (compared with the loss of its last epoch) but then increases till the end of this epoch. Below is an example:

```
Epoch [29][250/940] lr: 3.298e-04, top1_acc: 0.4903, top5_acc: 0.7323, loss: 2.2106, grad_norm: 1.8732
Epoch [29][500/940] lr: 3.298e-04, top1_acc: 0.4844, top5_acc: 0.7267, loss: 2.2330, grad_norm: 1.8848
Epoch [29][750/940] lr: 3.298e-04, top1_acc: 0.4850, top5_acc: 0.7247, loss: 2.2491, grad_norm: 1.8910

Epoch [30][250/940] lr: 3.055e-04, top1_acc: 0.4985, top5_acc: 0.7384, loss: 2.1676, grad_norm: 1.9173
Epoch [30][500/940] lr: 3.055e-04, top1_acc: 0.4971, top5_acc: 0.7356, loss: 2.1739, grad_norm: 1.9099
Epoch [30][750/940] lr: 3.055e-04, top1_acc: 0.4962, top5_acc: 0.7341, loss: 2.1861, grad_norm: 1.9269

Epoch [31][250/940] lr: 2.816e-04, top1_acc: 0.5119, top5_acc: 0.7454, loss: 2.1087, grad_norm: 1.9586
Epoch [31][500/940] lr: 2.816e-04, top1_acc: 0.5071, top5_acc: 0.7435, loss: 2.1329, grad_norm: 1.9674
Epoch [31][750/940] lr: 2.816e-04, top1_acc: 0.5076, top5_acc: 0.7436, loss: 2.1296, grad_norm: 1.9738
```

The training loss curve is:
[image]
The pattern of `decrease-then-increase in each epoch` of training loss is very stable but it only happens at the the later part of the training. So it should not be the problem of codes.

Is there a genius can explain this?

Comment: are you shuffling your training data? This would happen if you were going in batches through training set in a fixed order

Comment: @lejlot I am using a third-party repo for training. The shuffling should be True.( I tried my best to review their codes, and the conclusion is the same). Is my pattern highly relative to the shuffling? If so, I will go deeper to their code to check the shuffling.

Comment: Periodic pattern in the loss is usually a result of not shuffling, as it just can correspond to losses on specific parts of your training set. The only other source of a periodic pattern that I am aware of would be a periodic element of training itself, e.g. cosine schedule of learning rate etc.

Comment: @lejlot I tried my best to check the shuffling, but I see no problem. Anyway, thanks for your comments. I will try something else.